# Is there a symbol I can use as a substitute for a word or part of a word (similar to how ◌ is used for diacritics)?

Tags: symbols

I am making a chart that illustrates prefixes, suffixes and middles of words in Braille, and I was wondering if there is a symbol I can use to represent word, part of word or rest of word, similar to how `◌` is often used in diacritics examples. I would like to avoid the hyphen as there is some specific Braille for dealing with that.

For example (just using ◌)

- ◌tion
- dis◌
- ◌dd◌

Comment: Hm, kinda like `∼` then, you mean?

Comment: I don't think this fits on EL&U. Linguistics?

Comment: Doesn't fit because it's not English related.

Comment: @MετάEd Where would it fit?

Comment: TimLymington suggested [linguistics.se]. If anybody's using such a thing, they are. Possibly you might also get some help at [graphicdesign.se].

Answer (score 2):

Hypens are often used to denote missing information like -ing words or sub- words.

Comment: What about where I have just the middle of the word? Also hyphens are problematic as I don't want to get any confusion with the braille for a hyphen or any of braille's myriad abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [wildcard characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character). A good example of their use can be seen on [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/):

```
bluebird    Find definitions of bluebird
blue*       Find words and phrases that start with blue
*bird       Find words and phrases that end with bird
bl????rd    Find words that start with bl, end with rd, and have 4 letters in between
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion, and I would normally use that except for the same reasons I need to avoid the hyphen.